# What is the rule of thumb for land/taking-off on a sloped runway?

Tags: takeoff, runways

Skyvector lists the gradient for [KMCI](http://skyvector.com/airport/MCI/Kansas-City-International-Airport) as 0.3%.  What is the rule of thumb for how large a gradient needs to be before you always take off downhill and always land uphill like they do at [Lukla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenzing-Hillary_Airport)?  Assume winds are not a factor.

Comment: actually the reason for only taking off in one direction is terrain. [you won't be able to drop to the tarmac after clearing the hill behind it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:RK_0602_00811_LuklaAnflug.jpg)

Comment: A runway with an uphill grade is equivalent to a shorter runway with no grade. You might ask in Physics for the formula.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: Well, VNLK has 12% gradient and that is itself steeper than both descent and climb gradient of most planes, considering the 9 200 ft altitude.

Comment: 12% is 6.875 degrees! http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=12%25+in+degrees

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**What does your POH/AFM says?**

Ignoring winds and other factors, it depends on **effective runway length**, not just runway length. If you have a runway long (really long) enough, you can takeoff/land in either direction.

As mentioned [here](http://principalair.ca/article%20-%20Runway%20Slope.htm):

> ... advantage or disadvantage of a sloped runway is that a 1% runway
>   gradient — an increase or decrease in altitude of 10’ for every 1000’
>   of runway length — is equivalent to a 10% increase or decrease in
>   *effective runway length* ...

Example:

*Runway length is 1500' with 3% up-slope gradient*

- Landing uphill on it will give us an *effective runway length* of almost 2000’ (1500’ x 1.3 = 1950’).
- Landing downhill on it will give us an *effective runway length* of just over 1000’ (1500’ x 0.7 = 1050’).

---

Just for reference, the runway (6: uphill; 24: downhill) at Lukla Airport has 12% gradient and is 1500' long.

Effective Runway Lengths (using the formula above)

```
 6: 1500' x |(1+1.2)| = 3300'
24: 1500' x |(1-1.2)| =  300'
```

Hence, hypothetically speaking, if runway 24 is 48,400' long with no wind, A380 [can](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A380#Specifications) takeoff too.

Comment: Except that you can't land downhill on anything steeper than your descent gradient _at all_. And you can't take-off uphill from anything steeper than your climb gradient _at all_ either. And in multi-engine you obviously wouldn't attempt to take off uphill steeper than your one engine inoperative climb gradient. Normal descent gradient is 5%, Lukla has 12% (and Courchevel has 18%).

Comment: @JanHudec Good Point. That's why I said *hypothetically*, not theoretically or practically. Even with no wind, there are many other factors too. I also started the answer with `Ignoring winds and other factors...`.

Comment: By the way, how do you justify the absolute value? The rule does not say any such thing. The effective length for takeoff on 10% uphill/landing 10% is 0 according to the rule and for steeper gradient it therefore _should_ be negative (so it is _minus_ 300' for landing on VNLK 24)

Comment: @JanHudec I did that because length is a scalar quantity, but I do agree with your example.

Answer (score 6):

I happened to be looking at some takeoff distance charts, so I looked into this. As Tyler says, the answer will depend on your airplane's performance. With good brakes and plenty of runway, a small plane may not care as much as a larger one. The following applies to the PC-12.

I know you said to assume winds are not a factor, but it may help to roughly relate the effects of slope and wind. It turns out that 4% of slope will either help or hurt about the same amount as 10 kt of wind (within about 7%). Both provide around 10% benefit or 25% penalty on takeoff distance, and landing distance is affected by slope a bit less and wind a bit more. This would provide a good sense of how much a slope will affect the runway length you need. That penalty will certainly start to hurt as slope increases.

Answer (score 2):

There is no firm guideline. It depends on wind conditions and other factors like the surrounding terrain.

I have landed at [Jaffrey](http://www.airnav.com/airport/KAFN) only uphill, which has a 0.9% grade and a bad surface, but people can and do land there downhill. It is very steep for an air strip. If the wind was strong enough I would have no problem landing downhill there, but with moderate winds I would always go uphill.

Comment: OP wrote "Assume winds are not a factor."

Comment: Well, if there is no wind and no terrain you would normally land uphill on a graded runway if it has a listed gradient.

Comment: OP wanted to know how a grade figures into the aeronautical decision-making to land downhill or take off uphill, and if there's a rule-of-thumb. for example, runway 01 is 2500 feet long and downhill, and you're approaching from the south. Would you make a straight in, or circle at .5%? 1%? 5%?